# Can't get bluetooth to work on HP Laptop

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, laptop, hp, 21.04

I've been trying for weeks to try and get bluetooth drivers for my HP Laptop, It has a Realtek RTL8821CE WiFi and Bluetooth 4.2 Combo chip in it, I tried multiple drivers I found on tons of different forums but ubuntu still doesn't recognize bluetooth, it uses the chip for wifi but says that there is no bluetooth adapters in the system and that a dongle is required in settings. Can anyone help?

EDIT: Here are my results from doing lscpi

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b71 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9b21 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP Shared SRAM
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SATA AHCI Controller
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0285
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

Results from lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bc2:a013 Seagate RSS LLC Backup+ BK
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 03f0:2141 HP, Inc HP Wireless Mouse 220 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Results from `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
[  998.047075] audit: type=1107 audit(1625930071.455:140): pid=1462 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=4548 label="snap.twinux.twinux"
```

(I was asked by a comment to do these commands)

Comment: share more info like "lspci", "lsusb" rfkill and all that stuff don't just bluetooth not working.

Comment: May we also see: `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I have edited my original post to include my results from these commands, I tried to just reply to your comment with them but was told the comment was too long, sorry i don't know much about how to use this forum since I joined just to ask about the bt drivers

Answer (score 0):

As alternate to spend your time to get outdated BT 4.2 card working, you can order for 10€ to 15 USD incl. transport a wifi 6 card incl. BT 5.1, which is supported by ubuntu 21.04 without some research by standard.

```
A working one Wifi6 / BT5.1 card are p.e. a intel AX200
```

Comment: Well I was hoping I wouldn't have to spend any money since I currently don't have a job and only have about 5 bucks on my card rn, but if im unable to find any drivers ill probably just get a 6 dollar dongle or smth

Comment: As i was on same situation like you, (its not a joke) I worked one hour for my neighbor an he ordered the 15USD card for me.

Comment: I'll ask my neighbor if i can do some work for them but I'm gonna try and just find some drivers first, mostly cause i dont trust my clumsy ass to take apart my laptop and put a new card in lmao